# Getting substring from String in java

Tags: java, string

I have a string that contains data with different values, something like

```
String values = "firstname=john&lastname=fob&email=something@something.com&Telephone=3874813781"
```

FYI: `&` is the separator.

I want to make a new string for all these parameters - firstname, lastname, email and etc... - and I want the string to contain only the value of it specific parameter something like

```
String firstname = "john";
```

and same for `lastname` and so on. I think it is not better to use

```
String firstname = values.indexOf(10);
```

because I don't know how many characters would the *username* contain so I could go for lastname an so, I was wondering if there is a better way for getting the values of each parameter and assign it to a new string.

Comment: Use ```String.split("&");```  which will return an array of Strings which are seperated with ```&``` .

Comment: so it would be like `String firstname = values.split("&");`

Comment: @jacky : You can see my answer to get a clarification.

Comment: See the answer I have written with proper syntax and given sample output also for the input string you have given.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split method.
Use `values.split("&")` , this will return you an array of Strings.

```
String values = "firstname=john&lastname=fob&email=something@something.com&Telephone=3874813781";
String[] parameters = values.split("&");
System.out.println(parameters[0]); // Prints firstname=john
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working just the way i wanted!

Comment: @jacky : No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `String values_seperated[] = values.split("&");` Which will give you an `array of Strings`.

so here `elements of values_seperated[] array` will be:

```
values_seperated[0]:firstname=john
values_seperated[1]:lastname=fob
values_seperated[2]:email=something@something.com
values_seperated[3]:Telephone=3874813781
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] split = values.split("&");

String firstname = null, lastname = null, email = null, Telephone = null;

for (String string : split) {
    String[] parts = string.split("=");
    String key = parts[0];
    String value = parts[1];

    switch (key) {
    case "firstname":
        firstname = value;
        break;
    case "lastname":
        lastname = value;
        break;
    case "email":
        email = value;
        break;
    case "Telephone":
        Telephone = value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a function in java that separates java tokens based on a delimiter that you want. The following solution assumes that the same sequence of parameters in the values string will be used:

```
    String values =  "firstname=john&lastname=fob&email=something@something.com&Telephone=3874813781";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(values,"&");
    String nextToken; 

    nextToken=st.nextToken();
    String firstname=nextToken.substring(nextToken.indexOf("=")+1);

    nextToken=st.nextToken();
    String lastname=nextToken.substring(nextToken.indexOf("=")+1);

    nextToken=st.nextToken();
    String email=nextToken.substring(nextToken.indexOf("=")+1);

    nextToken=st.nextToken();
    String Telephone=nextToken.substring(nextToken.indexOf("=")+1);

    System.out.println(firstname+" "+lastname+" "+email+" "+Telephone);
```

*StringTokenizer(values,"&")* splits the String into multiple tokens
Then one by one you can assign the values to the respective variables.

*st.nextToken()* fetches tokens one by one